# Electron handle event in two React components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

I am using Electron along with React. I have two components in React that both talk to the main Electron file. The `main.js` file looks like this

```
// main process
window.ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

...

win.webContents.send('important-event');
```

My first component looks like this

```
// Component 1
const { ipcRenderer } = window;

...

ipcRenderer.on('important-event', () => { /* Do stuff */ })
```

My second component looks like this

```
// Component 2
const { ipcRenderer } = window;

...

ipcRenderer.on('important-event', () => { /* Do stuff */ })
```

The problem that I have here is that an event can only be caught one time. So `component 1` catches the event and does some stuff, but `component 2` doesn't.

Is there a way to send a single event that can get caught multiple times by different components?

Comment: I would catch this event a single time "above" your component. You could use a [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) provided to both components, or a parent component that passes information about the event down to these 2 components as children.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I could set up a context store, or just provide a parent component to these two to pass down props to them. I wonder if there is a lazier way to implement this. If not, your solution is probably the best one.

Comment: Another (maybe lazier) way to implement this would be to create your own event emitter as a module and have it listen to that event and fire it to all of its subscribers. Then just subscribe to your emitter in those 2 components.

Comment: Ah, now that's a lazy answer I was looking for!

Comment: Note that one benefit of using context is that its state will persist even if you dismount and later remount those components. Just something to keep in mind!